# Ways to Replace Null Values with Crystal Reports 2008 (not formula solution)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, crystal-reports

I'm working with Crystal reports. I have made many reports. And recently I was told, that null values should be printed as text ('no value') and not blank. I understand that I should create formula:

```
If isnull({some_field}) then 'no value' else {some_field}
```

and put this formula on report. But this will take many pointless hours. Are there any shorter way?

My enviroment: Crystal reports 2008 and Oracle db.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify the query

```
SELECT decode(column_name, null,'No Value',column_name) from table1
```

Column_name would be your concerned column. (be aware of the datatype in case your applications say to be a `NUMBER` then this string *would be a problem*)

Comment: Well, yes I have few fields with number datatype. I come to a solution using this query:

`select
NVL(name1, 'No Value') as name1,
NVL(code1, 'No Value') as code1
from table1`

But I have to specify each field individualy, can't this be somehow applied to all fields in the table?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this thing from database end.